# Why doesn't my fourth grid element display well?

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-grid

I'm using a WordPress theme which is using bootstrap 3.4.1.

I have an issue with a grid, the fourth element is displayed in place of where the hypothetical 6th element should be.
Here's a snippet taken from my code, yet I couldn't make it appear like it is on my website. https://codepen.io/pierrick-pi-gallagher/pen/poWyvpY

Here you can see what I'm talking about.

[image: Here you can see what I'm talking about.]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="adforest_res">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="posts-masonry">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="holder-806">
            <div class="white category-grid-box-1">
              <div class="image">
                <div style="position: absolute; top: 38px; left: 0px;background-color: black;color: white;z-index: 1000;padding: 5px;">Recherche</div>
                <div class="ribbon status_active" id="status-dyn-806">Actif</div>
                <a href="https://www.hoppyconnect.com/ad/blonde-de-soif-bec-permanent-6-mois/"><img src="https://www.hoppyconnect.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/logo-konrad-carre-80x80.png" alt="Blonde de soif – bec permanent – 6 mois" style="width: 40%;left: 30%;margin-top: 18% !important;margin-bottom: 17%;" class="img-responsive"></a>
              </div>
              <a href="https://www.hoppyconnect.com/ad/blonde-de-soif-bec-permanent-6-mois/">
                <div class="short-description-1 text-center">
                  <div class="category-title" style="font-size: 14px !important;font-weight:300;color: black !important">Contrats permanents</div>
                  <h2 class="text-center" style="font-size: 14px !important;font-weight:300;color: black !important">Blonde</h2>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-left" style="font-size: 14px !important;font-weight:300;color: black !important">
                      Non renseigné
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-right" style="font-size: 14px !important;font-weight:300;color: black !important">
                      6 mois min</div>
                  </div>

                  <span class="ad-price" style="text-align: center !important;float:none;font-size: 14px !important;font-weight:300;color: black !important">2,40 €/L HTDI</span>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="holder-757">
            <div class="white category-grid-box-1">
              <div class="image">
                <div style="position: absolute; top: 38px; left: 0px;background-color: black;color: white;z-index: 1000;padding: 5px;">Recherche</div>
                <div class="ribbon status_active" id="status-dyn-757">Actif</div><a href="https://www.hoppyconnect.com/ad/d-check-offre-contrat-permanent-1-biere/"><img src="https://www.hoppyconnect.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/logo-konrad-carre-80x80.png" alt="D-CHECK – Offre > Contrat permanent > 1 bière" style="width: 40%;left: 30%;margin-top: 18% !important;margin-bottom: 17%;" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
              <a href="https://www.hoppyconnect.com/ad/d-check-offre-contrat-permanent-1-biere/">
                <div class="short-description-1 text-center">
                  <div class="category-title" style="font-size: 14px !important;font-weight:300;color: black !important">Contrats permanents</div>
                  <h2 class="text-center" style="font-size: 14px !important;font-weight:300;color: black !important">Double IPA</h2>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-left" style="font-size: 14px !important;font-weight:300;color: black !important">
                      Non renseigné
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-right" style="font-size: 14px !important;font-weight:300;color: black !important">
                      12 mois min</div>
                  </div>

                  <span class="ad-price" style="text-align: center !important;float:none;font-size: 14px !important;font-weight:300;color: black !important">2,30 €/L HTDI</span>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="holder-710">
            <div class="white category-grid-box-1">
              <div class="image">
                <div style="position: absolute; top: 38px; left: 0px;background-color: black;color: white;z-index: 1000;padding: 5px;">Recherche</div>
                <div class="ribbon status_active" id="status-dyn-710">Actif</div>
                <a href="https://www.hoppyconnect.com/ad/test-bec-permanent-1-biere/"><img src="https://www.hoppyconnect.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/shutterstock_402621667-1-2-313x234.jpg" alt="(Test) bec permanent 1 bière" class="img-responsive"></a>
              </div>
              <a href="https://www.hoppyconnect.com/ad/test-bec-permanent-1-biere/">
                <div class="short-description-1 text-center">
                  <div class="category-title" style="font-size: 14px !important;font-weight:300;color: black !important">Contrats permanents</div>
                  <h2 class="text-center" style="font-size: 14px !important;font-weight:300;color: black !important">Ambrée</h2>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-left" style="font-size: 14px !important;font-weight:300;color: black !important">
                      Non renseigné
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-right" style="font-size: 14px !important;font-weight:300;color: black !important">
                      12 mois min</div>
                  </div>

                  <span class="ad-price" style="text-align: center !important;float:none;font-size: 14px !important;font-weight:300;color: black !important">1,11 €/L HTDI</span>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="holder-707">
            <div class="white category-grid-box-1">
              <div class="image">
                <div style="position: absolute; top: 38px; left: 0px;background-color: black;color: white;z-index: 1000;padding: 5px;">Recherche</div>
                <div class="ribbon status_active" id="status-dyn-707">Actif</div>
                <a href="https://www.hoppyconnect.com/ad/bec-blonde-6-mois-dengagement-mini/"><img src="https://www.hoppyconnect.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/shutterstock_402621667-1-1-313x234.jpg" alt="Bec blonde – 6 mois d’engagement mini" class="img-responsive"></a>
              </div>

              <a href="https://www.hoppyconnect.com/ad/bec-blonde-6-mois-dengagement-mini/">
                <div class="short-description-1 text-center">
                  <div class="category-title" style="font-size: 14px !important;font-weight:300;color: black !important">Contrats permanents</div>
                  <h2 class="text-center" style="font-size: 14px !important;font-weight:300;color: black !important">Barley wine</h2>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-left" style="font-size: 14px !important;font-weight:300;color: black !important">
                      Non renseigné
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-right" style="font-size: 14px !important;font-weight:300;color: black !important">
                      12 mois min</div>
                  </div>

                  <span class="ad-price" style="text-align: center !important;float:none;font-size: 14px !important;font-weight:300;color: black !important">12,00 €/L HTDI</span>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I don't understand since it's perfectly working on another page of my website with the same code.

I can't give link on my website since it is on coming soon mode.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback, I added a link to a codepen since stack overflow doesn't want more than 30000 characters. But I couldn't make it appear like it is on my website even with adding modern.css, but the same problem is there and can be viewed.

Comment: If so, the main problem is that you've taken a layout library and warped it with absolute positioning on the columns. Don't do that. Don't mess with the grid. Take all the styles off that and put them on the grid _contents_, using custom classes and an embedded style tag or external stylesheet. Don't use inline styling. Avoid absolute positioning to begin with unless you know you really need it.

Comment: In your snippet, is bootstrap 3.3.7. I said I was using bootstrap 3.4.1.
Also, the inline style is automatically added to the html in my website. I have absolutely no absolute inline css positioning in my code. I just copy/pasted the html from console as you said.
Also, the result in your snippet does not look as the image in my post. The codepen link I have given is much more relatable.

Comment: Since the styles are also added in the page that is working, I assume this is not the issue I want to solve ?

Comment: @isherwood now it's working: https://codepen.io/pierrick-pi-gallagher/pen/poWyvpY

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to tell you what but the theme you're using is really badly written, there is more than 14k lines of CSS with multiple typos like on line 4970 `position: realtive;`.

There is no use of [CSS grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) but 192 uses of `position: absolute;` and 273 uses of `!important`.

In the HTML part there is class applied on div that aren't in the CSS like `posts-masonry`.

In every items on your *"grid"* there is this style directly applied on the HTML:

```css
position: absolute;
left: Xpx;
top: Xpx;
```

it looks like these values have been applied by javascript.

To conclude, we won't be able to help fix this grid issue since the best way would be to re-write the grid system entirely.

Comment: Wow.... That's really pertinent, thanks, our freelancer did all wrong...

Thanks for taking the time to get deeper.